# CSS make footer bellow a grid and float

Tags: css

I have a left column float: left and a right one with a grid both with some containers.
When I apply a margin-top:60px to the footer which is bellow it starts going up from the grid at the right but its containers doesn't go as far the ones on the left column so the footer overlaps.

How could I make the footer be rendered after the furthest column (which isn't necessarily the right one)?

My CSS:

```
.article-list {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.article {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.list {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 280px);
    grid-gap: 30px;
}

.list-card {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 270px;
    height: 260px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.footer {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

My left float column HTML:

```
<div class="article-list">
    <div class="article">
        <h3>Categories</h3>
        <p>Category</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My right grid column HTML:

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="list-card">
        <p>My right list containers...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My footer HTML:

```
<footer class="footer">
    <h5>Footer content...</h5>
</footer>
```

Comment: Also, how could I make it only bellow the right column?

Answer (score 0):

You meant something like this?

```css
.article-list {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.article {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.list {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 280px);
    grid-gap: 30px;
}

.list-card {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 270px;
    height: 260px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.footer {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.stack_overflow_fix {
    display: flex;
    align-items: start;
}
```

```html
<div class='stack_overflow_fix'>
  <div class="article-list">
      <div class="article">
          <h3>Categories</h3>
          <p>Category</p>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="list">
      <div class="list-card">
          <p>My right list containers...</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
    <h5>Footer content...</h5>
</footer>
```